# Is there way to parse tr returned by 'this'?

Tags: javascript

Each row of my table has a button at the end of the row, which has an addEventListener like this,

```
button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
   deleteSummary(this);
});

function deleteSummary(oButton)
{
    console.log(oButton.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML)
}
```

the console.log shows like this,

```
<td>966</td><td>TypeA</td><td>1234</td><td>10,000</td><td>9,861</td><td>139</td><td>2021-01-02</td><td>3</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>7</td><td>89</td><td>9</td><td>8</td><td>7</td><td>1</td><td><button>delete</button></td>
```

But I have no idea how to parse(?) it.
I always found answers you use document.getElementById() when googling.

Thanks

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to achieve here. You already have a parsed version (it's `oButton.parentNode.parentNode`), you only *just* made a serialised copy with `innerHTML`.

Comment: Why are you wanting to parse that output? What's the goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @evolutionxbox tr should be sent to a server to delete a row matched with the tr. The format should be array. So I thought I needed to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not aim to parse HTML. You have access to the DOM, so stick with that. You already found the `tr` element successfully, and then you can for instance use its `cells` property to get access to all the `td` elements, and you could map that list of cells to their text content. That way you get a standard array with all the cell texts of that particular row.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("td>button");
for (let button of buttons) {
    // Your code:
    button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
       deleteSummary(this);
    });
}

function deleteSummary(oButton) {
   let tr = oButton.parentNode.parentNode;
   let data = Array.from(tr.cells, cell => cell.textContent);
   data.pop(); // Optional: get rid of the column with the delete button
   console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>966</td>
     <td>TypeA</td>
     <td>1234</td>
     <td>10,000</td>
     <td>2021-01-02</td>
     <td><button>delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>123</td>
     <td>TypeB</td>
     <td>9988</td>
     <td>29,999</td>
     <td>2020-09-20</td>
     <td><button>delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```